# Where can I get a huge json file?

Tags: javascript, json

Maybe this question is not in the stackoverflow questions topic, but I don't know where to ask this or how to get it, but I'm developing a project and I need an extremely large json file, just for performance tests, but I can't find it, anyone have any json file which is huge?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/0bce379832b475a6c21726ce37f971f8d849513b/large-file.json

Answer (score 3):

You should probably try using [this site](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Comment: Try if this helps. You can add any kind of object into the " " part.

```"{'hello':'10'},{'hey':100}".repeat(1000);```